# Why does Static member variable inherits the value when instantiatiing object number of times in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, static

i was testing the Static Keyword on how exactly does it work and i came across this which i don't understand what is happening.

Consider two Classes `ClassNameA` & `ClassNameB` with the following codes.

**ClassNameA without Static Keyword**

```
class ClassNameA
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct($value) {
        if($value != '') {
            $this->name = $value;
        }
        $this->getValue();
    }
    public function getValue() {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}
```

**ClassNameB with Static Keyword**

```
class ClassNameB
{
    private static $name;

    public function __construct($value) {
        if($value != '') {
            self::$name = $value;
        }
        $this->getValue();
    }
    public function getValue() {
        echo self::$name;
    }
}
```

When i instantiate the object multiple times using ClassNameA

```
$a = new ClassNameA(12);
echo '<br/>';
$a = new ClassNameA(23);
echo '<br/>';
$a = new ClassNameA(''); //Argument given is Empty here
```

it outputs the folowing

```
12
23
```

And now when i instantiate the object multiple times using ClassNameB

```
$a = new ClassNameB(12);
echo '<br/>';
$a = new ClassNameB(23);
echo '<br/>';
$a = new ClassNameB(''); //Argument given is Empty here
```

It outputs the following

```
12
23
23
```

Note the extra value 23 it is taking even if the Argument Passed is Empty. Is this a bug? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the nature of `static` property. The static property is a kind of property of class not the property of object.

When you passed the blank, according to the condition the value of static property will not get updated and last value is still there in the static property.

Since the static property is not bounded with any of the object hence it is available without a need any object.

```
$a = new ClassNameB(12); //static property is set to 12
echo '<br/>';
$a = new ClassNameB(23); //static property is update to 23
echo '<br/>';
$a = new ClassNameB(''); //static property is not updated here it is still 23
```

**EDIT**

You can understand like this:-

```
if($value != '') {
    $this->name = $value; //
 }
```

What the code above is doing it is setting the property value for current object (object which is initializing right now).

So when you wrote

```
$a = new ClassNameA(12);
```

What it is doing it is setting the `name` property to `12` for object `a`;

```
$a = new ClassNameA(23);
```

What it is doing it is setting the `name` property to `23` for object `a`;

But when the property is `static` that is for the whole class not for any object.

so when you wrote

```
if($value != '') {
    self::$name = $value;
 }
```

The code above is setting the static property value. Note that here you wrote `self` instead of `$this` which make it use for this class only and not for any of the object.

I tried to explain it better but don't know how it is explaining for you.

Comment: oh, so does that mean the scope of Static Variable is Global?

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation. i did understand what you are trying to say.:)

Answer (score 2):

A static member is a single instance across the entire application, not once per object. For example

```
class Example {
  static public $var;

  static public MyFunction() {
    echo "MyFunction\n";
  }
}

Example::$var = 123;
echo Example::$var;
Example::MyFunction();
```

Note how we did not need to create an instance of "Example", essentially its name-spacing the variable to the class. This would be invalid:

```
$example = new Example();
echo $example->var;
$example->MyFunction();
```

You can also reference it inside the class as

```
self::$var
self::MyFunction();
```

Which makes it safe to rename the class later if you need to. A static function can not access non static member or method though.

Comment: Ok so you mean to say once i declare it and initiate the object or if it have been loaded into the memory, it becomes global and i can access it anywhere?

Comment: It is global and can be accessed anywhere provided that it is scoped public. You can also have static methods.